# How do I analyze/determine the continuity of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

My question is really:the following: In general, how do I analyze/determine the continuity of a function? Is there some sort of algorithm?

Failing that, here's an example.

$$ f: \left]-1,1\right[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ x \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k\cos(kx) $$

I already figured out that the series always converges, so that the definition of $f$ makes sense.

Next, the only thing I can think of is this:
the series converges, the part $x^k$ is continuous, and the part $\cos(kx)$ is continuous, so the entire thing must be continuous.
This is, of course, very vague and I need to find a more rigorous argument.
There are no denominators to become zero or negative roots, so I can't seem to find a problem with the continuity.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the domain of $k$?

Comment: Great question, $k$ is a natural number. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a high-level algorithm: try to think about how much the function changes when you perturb its argument. As you observed, the function is built out of continuous parts so it has a good chance of being continuous. The only thing that could go wrong is if the function became wilder and wilder in oscillation with the higher order terms in the series. For a concrete example, thing of a the Fourier series for a square wave: it is a sum of continuous functions with greater and greater oscillation, whose limit is a step function (and therefore not continuous).

Of course, none of that craziness happens in this example, because the tail of the series dies out so quickly that for all practical purposes, we are working with a finite sum. That's the idea in my proof below:

Fix $x\in (-1,1)$ and choose $\varepsilon>0$. Choose a number $0<\delta_0<1-|x|$. Also choose a large number $N$ that satisfies $$\frac{(|x|+\delta_0)^N}{1-(|x|+\delta_0)}\leq \varepsilon/4$$
This bound lets us control the "tail" of the series.

Now to handle the first few terms: Consider the finite sum $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^N x^k\cos(kx)$. As a finite sum of continuous functions, this function is continuous. Hence there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $y$ with $|y-x|<\delta_1$, we have $|g(y)-g(x)|<\varepsilon/2$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,\delta_1\}$. We claim that for all $y$ which satisfy $|y-x|<\delta$, we have $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$ In order to prove this, we combine our existing bounds with the triangle inequality as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
|f(y)-f(x)|&\leq |g(y)-g(x)|+\left|\sum_{k>N}x^k\cos(kx)\right|+\left|\sum_{k>N}y^k\cos(ky)\right|\\
&\leq \varepsilon/2 + \sum_{k>N}(|x|^k + |y|^k)\\
&\leq \varepsilon/2 + \frac{|x|^N}{1-|x|}+\frac{|y|^N}{1-|y|}\\
&\leq \varepsilon/2 + 2\frac{(|x|+\delta_0)^N}{1-(|x|+\delta_0)}\\
&\leq \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$
We have used the fact that $|\cos(kx)|\leq 1$ and that $t^N/(1-t)$ is an increasing function in $t$.

Comment: Do you happen to know the limit function? This should not be this hard. I'm trying to find some other solutions..

Comment: I highly suspect that the limit function can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions and is not well-known.